# AttributeError at /admin/pizza/topping/add/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attname'

Tags: django

When i try to add entries from admin server i get the above error

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __init__(self):
        self.name_text

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self):
        self.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't override the `__init__` method of Django models, especially not in a way that skips calling the superclass `__init__`.

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

is just fine.

Comment: My previous models seemed to have worked with the method. But you are right by removing it Problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used `__init__` instead of `__str__`. `__str__` is used to provide a *string* representation of the object, `__init__` is used to *initialize* an object. You also need to *return* the result:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_text

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```